# How can I make my react native auto update without play store?

Tags: android, react-native, auto-update

my mobile app will used for internal business so, I didn't publish it on google 
But I ask , how can I make my app auto update when I make a new version of it, and how can I notify person who use this app with the new update?

Comment: you can use push notification. read up on firebase messaging. there is a tutorial [here](http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/06/Implementing-FCM-(-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-)-in-Android-App) that might help. Or you can simply call a web service which tell the current version (newest) and you can compare it to the current installed on and update the app

Answer (score 13):

There are a series of services available for issuing over-the-air updates to your Javascript, for instance [Code Push](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) by Microsoft is a comprehensive solution for managing releases and actually pushing them to devices.

Or if you want to implement the back-end yourself, [React Native Auto Updater](https://github.com/aerofs/react-native-auto-updater) handles the client-side checking/updating of code, with you just needing to implement the required APIs for information about versions/bundle downloads.